# Django admin inline - show only when changing object

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-admin

I have a `UserProfile` which has many required (not null but blank) fields and I'm trying not to show it when adding a user.

I tried multiple things, for example:

```
def get_formsets_with_inlines(self, request, obj=None):
    if not obj:
        return []
    return super().get_formsets_with_inlines(request, obj)
```

But after saving `User`, `django` raises error which says that fields from `UserProfile` can't be null.

Do you know how to make it work?

Comment: But how do you plan to add those required fields?

Comment: @DanielHolmes Those fields are just blank=False, not null=False. Users then can fill them on their profile page.

Comment: @Milano create a custom User class to override the default and set the specified fields to null=True in your model. Or else go to the already created model in your db probably `django_user` or something like this and alter the column attributes.

Comment: @KostasCharitidis this won't work, because setting null=True, won't prevent validation errors from being raised when blank=False. There is no easy way around this, apart from setting blank=True, and writing custom validation for the UserProfile.

Answer (score 6):

As of Django 3.0, there is a `ModelAdmin.get_inlines()` method, which you can override like this:

```
def get_inlines(self, request, obj=None):
    if obj:
        return [FirstInline, SecondInline]
    else:
        return []
```

[See Django Documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.get_inlines).

Answer (score 1):

ModelAdmin provides a method [get_inline_instances](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.get_inline_instances) for conditional inlines.

from the docs:

> The get_inline_instances method is given the HttpRequest and the obj
>   being edited (or None on an add form) and is expected to return a list
>   or tuple of InlineModelAdmin objects.

for example:

```
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = (MyInline,)

    def get_inline_instances(self, request, obj=None):
        return [inline(self.model, self.admin_site) for inline in self.inlines]
```

here you can check if obj is present or not.

One important point from the docs:

> **If you override this method, make sure that the returned inlines are
>   instances of the classes defined in inlines or you might encounter a
>   “Bad Request” error when adding related objects.**

Answer (score 0):

I use [**"get_inlines()" added to Django since v3.0**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.get_inlines) instead of **"inlines = ()"** as shown below so that **"AddressInline"** is not displayed when adding a user but it's displayed when changing a user:

```py
# "admin.py"

class AddressInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Address

@admin.register(CustomUser)
class CustomUserAdmin(UserAdmin):
    # inlines = (AddressInline,)
    
    # Here
    def get_inlines(self, request, obj=None):
        if obj:
            return (AddressInline,)
        else:
            return ()

    fieldsets = (
        # ...
    )
    add_fieldsets = (
        # ...
    )
```